# Handling a big data-frame in R

Tags: r, rest, graph, dataframe, mediawiki-api

I am building a R package to interact with the RESTful MediaWiki API. When coding a function to extract the graph of all links of one article, I have to manipulate a very big (500 row and 500 columns) data frame. Doing this, R is very slow and for one article (take for example the "nationalism" article) the all process take 20 hours.

Can you recommend me something to speed up things ?
To explain things more precisely, i give you the code of the "createGraph" function of my package :

```
#' Make the graph of the links of one page
#' 
#' @param title the title of a page
#' @param domain the wiki of a page
#' @return A graph object
#' @import igraph
#' @export
#' 

createGraph <- function(titre,domaine,namespace,contributors=F) {      
print(paste("Téléchargement des liens de l'article",titre,sep=" "))
  listLinks<-links(titre,domaine,namespace)

  print("Construction de la matrice d'adjacence du graphe")
  data<-data.frame(matrix("0",ncol = nrow(listLinks),nrow = nrow(listLinks)),row.names=listLinks$titre,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  for(i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    for(j in 1:ncol(data)) {
      data[i,j]<-isLink(listLinks$titre[i],listLinks$titre[j],domaine)
    }
   print(paste(i/nrow(data)-1,"%",sep=" "))
  }
  newRow<-rep(1,ncol(data))
  data<-rbind(data,newRow)
  rownames(data)[nrow(data)]<-titre
  data[,ncol(data)+1]<-1
  data[nrow(data),ncol(data)]<-isLink(titre,titre,domaine)
  names(data)<-c(listLinks$titre,titre)

  graph_from_adjacency_matrix(data)
  graph<-graph_from_adjacency_matrix(as.matrix(data),c("directed"))
  print("100 %")
}
```

Comment: 500 x 500 is not "very big". It's a rather small data.frame (even if the number of columns is pretty large).

Comment: First step: Profile your code to find the bottleneck.

Comment: Okay, you loop though all elements of the data.frame. Thats 250 k iterations. Of course that's going to be slow. Don't do this.

Comment: As Roland said, that is it. Read about different flavors of apply functions, and use those. For example instead of double for looping through a DF you should just do ` apply(DF, c(1,2), func) `

Comment: No `*apply` function will help with this. A vectorized solution is needed.

Comment: Okay so the problem is that a loop thought my DF, but what is a "vectorized" solution ? sorry if it's a doom question :)

Comment: A solution not using any R loops, but only loops implemented in the underlying C (or Fortran) code of R functions.

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know how to do this, can you show on this code how do this ?